# Planes duplicating on every plane of my tree particle system after converting to mesh

Tags: modeling, particles

I made a tree model using the sampling tree gen and I found that I didn't like the leaves so I deleted them and made my own plane with an image texture on it and used a particle system on the branches, after going into the modifier section and converting the particles to meshes, instead of it combining the particles they are all separate objects and when I try to join them together they get duplicated on every single other plane there is and I have removed all modifiers and geometry nodes from the trees and leaves I don't understand why.[image: BeforeJoining] [image: AfterJoining]

Answer (score 0):

The objects and data were linked together by selecting the object and selecting *Select Linked > Object & Data* then with everything selected I selected *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object and Data*.